# Is there a way to know if someone sent 2 consecutive messages in a channel in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to make a one word at a time story moderation bot, and I made it filter and delete messages with a space in them. Now I want to make sure people aren't sending 2 messages at a time in the channel, is this possible? And if so, how? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you provide the part of your code that is handling message events people will be able to give you more concrete answers. As a general answer: if you only need to make sure that a new message is not by the same user as the immediately prior message, you could use an object to store userIds by channel, e.g. `{"channel1Id":userWhoSentTheLastMessage, "channel2Id":...}`. Then when you are handling a new message you can check to see if the user sending that message also sent the last one and, if not, replace that user in the object for the next check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
app.on('message', async (firstMessage) => {
  const secondMessage = (await firstMessage.channel.awaitMessages((msg) => true, {
    max: 1,
  })).first();
  
  if (firstMessage.author.id !== secondMessage.author.id) {
    firstMessage.channel.send('Fail');
  } else {
    firstMessage.channel.send('Success');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change `send messages` permission in channel by [.overwritePermissions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions)

```js
channel.overwritePermissions(
       // You can get another role if you want
       channel.guild.roles.everyone,
       // Object of permissions
       { 'SEND_MESSAGES': false },
       // Optional
       'Ongoing story')
```